# identify programming language

Tags: programming-languages, haskell, sudoku

Please identify this programming language:

```
*Main> [ ((a,b,c),(d,e)) | 
    a <- [1..7], 
    b <- [2..8], 
    c <- [3..9], 
    d <- [1..8], 
    e <- [2..9], 
    a < b, 
    b < c, 
    d < e, 
    List.intersect [d,e] [a,b,c] == [], 
    a+b+c == 23, 
    d+e == 10 ]
```

output:

```
[((6,8,9),(3,7))]
```

I found the code in [this blog comment](http://blog.hackensplat.com/2009/11/computers-are-fast.html?showComment=1286925147760#c8469605192701150112).

Comment: +1 for finding a blog comment with Haskell

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info), running in a [GHCi](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/ghci.html) session.

> [image]

Comment: How did you type this with less than 15 characters? :-)

Answer (score 3):

[Haskell](http://www.haskell.org). Definitely.

Answer (score 3):

[Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/), of course